# How to fetch initial state in redux at first, then I can use it in my component method?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react.js with `redux` to build my project. 
Currently, I store users' token in global state. But how to fetch the token before every component mount? For example. I have an `axios action` in `redux` to fetch data from REST API in `ComponentDidMount`:

Now, this method will goes to catch in `ComponenDidMount`  becuase it cannot fetch the the token (it is null at first and stored in another reducer).

```
  componentDidMount() {
       this.props.loadProfile()
      }


// in actions
export const loadProfile = (token) => {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(loadProfileStart())
        const getUrl = URL + 'myprofile/'
        return axios.get(getUrl, {
            headers: {
                ...HEADERS,
                'Authorization': 'Token ' + token // token is in another reducer,
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(loadProfileSuccess(res.data.profile))
                return res.data.profile

            })
            .catch(err => {

                dispatch(loadProfileFail(err))
                throw (err)
            })
    }
}
```

I did some research which said I should use `middleware`. But I still dont understand the getState because my store is in`App.js`

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, compostEnhancer(
    applyMiddleware(thunk )
))

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at this solution? https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/ It's long but it goes in depth on when and where to call the auth api.

Answer (score 0):

in my project if test in App constructor if user is logged in. For that, i control in my redux state my variable isLoggedIn. I use mapStateToProps for this.

If isLoggedIn i get token from API and i save him in localstorage then i show home componant else is !isLoggedIn i show loggin componant. 
I hope this way help you a little.

Comment: Previously, I was doing that with localstorage. But the others told me that it is not safe to store the token in the localstorage. Is it true?

Comment: Yes i store token in localstorage because we do not need a lot of security for our internal software. The best way is here : https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens . Eventually I will change my place of storage to put it in a cookie.